# MySQL select from two column table

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

i have a table with only 2 columns.
for example

```
table product.combinations
Column 1: product.id
Column 2: attribute.id
```

Product.id is unique
every product can have 1 or more attributes.
Products without attributes are not in the table

for example

table product.combinations

### product.id | attribute.id

```
  1    |     1      |
  1    |     2      |
  2    |     1      |
  2    |     2      |
  5    |     1      |
  5    |     3      |
  9    |     2      |
  9    |     3      |
  9    |     5      |
```

Now i would like to do a select with the result below

### product.id | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 |attribute 4 | attribute 5

```
  1    |     1      |    2       |            |            |
  2    |     1      |    2       |            |            |
  5    |     1      |    3       |            |            |
  9    |     2      |    3       |     5      |            |
```

i have already tried with a pivot but i was not able to hae o good result.
Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: There's a function `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL, it allows you to combine column values in a grouped statement.

Comment: Yes, i have read something about that but i think it's also concattenating the values in one column. I would like to have all values in separated columns with a column alias as title

Answer (score 1):

First: DO NOT use dots/periods in table/column names, this won't work, use underscores instead.

Second, if it is ok to have all attribute ids in a comma-separated list, you can do the following (using MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function):

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id ORDER BY attribute_id) AS attributes
    -> FROM product_combinations
    -> GROUP BY product_id
    -> ORDER BY product_id;
+------------+---------------+
| product_id | attributes    |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 | 1,2           |
|          2 | 1,2           |
|          5 | 1,3           |
|          9 | 2,3,5         |
+------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work but indeed separated with a comma. Is it possible to display it in separated columns.  somewhere else i found    select p.id_product_attribute, p.id_attribute, count(*) as seqnum
from ps_product_attribute_combination p left outer join
     ps_product_attribute_combination pprev
     on p.id_product_attribute = pprev.id_product_attribute and
        p.id_attribute >= pprev.id_attribute
group by p.id_product_attribute, p.id_attribute     the result is a three column table and the extra column has a title segnum and counts the position for every attribute of the product

Comment: sorry lay-out is terrible

Comment: Yes, that would work, however, than you will still have one line for each product<>attribute combination. What's wrong with a comma-separated list? You can explode that list in PHP for example or use it for comparisons in MySQL by using `IN(...)`.

Comment: yes indeed then i have still one line for each product. I would like to have it like in my example above. Because it is the start of a more complex join of tables.

Comment: Still, there's no point in having a column for each attribute. What if you have one product with hundreds of attributes? You would end up with hundreds of columns. This way, there's one single column for attributes and you can address that column exactly. What you do with the result, depends on your application, but I can't think of a scenario where it would be better to have separate columns, mind to expand your question on that?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT ATTRIBUTE
FROM combinations 
UNION ALL
SELECT ATTRIBUTE
FROM combinations

Comment: Yes, the dot was a typo. they are all underscores.

Comment: I tried the first answer and this seems to work but indeed they are separated with a comma. Is it possible to dsiplay it in separated columns?

Comment: The answer from Tushar had only 1 column as result.